# Is ElGamal secure if we fix the generator for all users?

Tags: elgamal-encryption

In the ElGamal cipher, the key generation algorithm needs to *randomly* sample a generator g and test whether g is a safe generator or not each time. I wonder whether we can use a fixed safe generator for all users, which may reduce the time of key generation. Will this be safe?

Answer (score 2):

The generator $g$ is always assumed to be public and does not need to be generated as part of the KeyGen. Specifically, the whole Diffie-Hellman group description (which includes $g$) can fixed. For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption#Key_generation

Comment: What's more, in elliptic-curve ElGamal, the base-point is almost always fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: I think I understand now ... The reason that ElGamal is described in a _random_ generator way is to prove its security under a weaker assumption (HDH). For a fixed generator, we need a stronger assumption ...